# Polynomials $f(x)$ of degree at most $5$ forming a ring and field

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

> Show that the set of all polynomials $f(x)$ of degree at most $5$ with integer coefficients is a ring. Is the set of such polynomials a field?

I don't see how the ring of polynomials with degree at most $5$ is closed under multiplication. If I multiply $x^2$ and $x^5$ I do not get another polynomial of degree at most $5$.

Comment: Well, they are not a ring, so it is not surprising that you cannot see it!

Comment: $\:\mathbb Z\:$ is the only subring of $\rm\:\mathbb Z[x]\:$ of bounded degree. Check the question.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it's not a ring using addition and multiplication defined in the normal manner on $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Are you sure that this is what the question asks? Does it perhaps introduce some equivalence relation, such as $x\equiv y$ iff $x-y\in (X^6)$?

Comment: The question was a typo on my professor's part. He wanted to show that Z[X]/x^6=1 was a ring.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured.